# Service broker - Reusing conversation - Problem of deadlock

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I am re using the conversation as per Remus Rusanu's blog http://rusanu.com/2007/05/03/recycling-conversations/. The event flows from initiator to target. Please note that my service broker implementation processes around 40 to 60 events per second.

I have used 6 hour as the life of a conversation handle.

Majority of the time I have no problem and the event flows nicely. The handle expires after 6 hour and then new handle gets created. All the clean up happens as per the plan.

Sometime though I am facing the errorcode 1205 inside initiator stored procedure (i.e. `usp_SenderActivation`), then resulting in roll back. This error is happening exactly at the time when old handle expires and new handle gets created.

Upon further investigation I realized that when the handle gets selected from the `SessionConversations` table, immediately after that the handle gets expired. This results in sending an event using a expired handle.

Has anyone experienced this? Any help?

Thanks,
Suvendu.